# How can Cooper communicate with his daughter before the time he went to space?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In the movie *Interstellar* it's shown that after Cooper fell into the Black Hole, he communicates with his daughter Murph through some codes as Ghost.
My doubt is how can he communicate to his daughter before he goes into space?
I didn’t get the logic of that part. Can anyone please make it clear?

Comment: i dont know how to hide the part which contains the movie story. please someone edit the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When cooper got pulled in Gargantua and ejected before spacecraft got destroyed, he got stuck in some extra dimension where time is non-linear. It's like a space where he can communicate with her daughter on earth through gravity. That's why Murph thought it was a ghost. So he can communicate with past time Murph because of the non-linear time structure of that extra dimension.

This extra dimension space can be treated as parallel plane which can assess multiple time frames of earth.

Comment: Ok then, take Cooper out of this equation for a second... who did communicate with his daughter in the first place?

Comment: The ghost was always Cooper.  Time is looping around on itself, so future Cooper can communicate with past Murph.  IIRC, there was a (very brief) moment where Cooper hypothesizes that the 'parallel plane' inside the black hole was a 'hypercube/tesseract,' artificially constructed by humans in the distant future and sent backwards through time to save his life and, by extension, the entire human race using the unique properties inside a black hole to defy the normal laws of space-time.  This hypothesis was never substantiated within the movie, but it makes more sense than "random black hole BS"